# SQL, retrieve one line with Max rule

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I want to be able to have in the Data extension the information of the opportunity, the account, the opportunity product and the product information.
I need to establish a rule to select the opportunity product that have the highest price. I need to have linked to the product the information as the product code. If I do this, I will only have one line per opportunity with the highest product information. For the moment, I am quite stuck and it gives me the error : Error saving the Query field.Invalid column name 'AccountId'.

```sql
Select
opportunity.Id                                as OPP_Id,
opportunity.Name                              as OPP_Name,
opportunity.StageName                         as OPP_Stage,
opportunity.Loss_Reason__c                    as OPP_RaisonDeLaPerte,
opportunity.LeadSource                        as OPP_LeadSource,
opportunity.Pr_cision_source__c               as OPP_PrecisionSource,
opportunity.Amount                            as OPP_Amount,
opportunity.IsWon                             as OPP_IsWon,
opportunity.MYOPLA__c                         as OPP_Myopla,
opportunity.MarqueGroupe__c                   as OPP_MarqueGroupe,
opportunity.CreatedDate                       as OPP_CreatedDate,
opportunity.CloseDate                         as OPP_CloseDate,
opportunity.LastModifiedDate                  as OPP_LastModifiedDate,
opportunity.Cat_gorie_Produits__c             as OPP_CategorieProduit,
account.FirstName                             as ACC_FirstName,
account.LastName                              as ACC_LastName,
account.IsPersonAccount                       as ACC_IsPersonAccount,
account.ShippingCity                          as ACC_ShippingCity,
account.ShippingCountry                       as ACC_ShippingCountry,
account.ShippingStreet                        as ACC_ShippingStreet,
account.ShippingPostalCode                    as ACC_ShippingPostalCode,
account.PersonEmail                           as ACC_Email,
account.PersonMobilePhone                     as ACC_Mobile,
account.et4ae5__Mobile_Country_Code__pc       as ACC_MobileCountryCode,
account.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail              as ACC_DesabonnementEmail,
account.et4ae5__HasOptedOutOfMobile__pc       as ACC_DesabonnementMobile,
account.CreatedDate                           as ACC_CreatedDate,
account.Account_Source__pc                    as ACC_AccountSource,
account.Precision_source__c                   as ACC_PrecisionSource,
account.Marque_groupe__c                      as ACC_MarqueGroupe,
account.NbDeCommandesPassees__c               as ACC_NbCommandesPassees,
account.TECH_PanierMoyen__c                   as ACC_PanierMoyen,
account.TECH_DateDerniereCommande__c          as ACC_DateDerniereCommande,
account.TECH_MontantDeLaDerniereCommande__c   as ACC_MontantDerniereCommande,
account.TECH_NbCases__pc                      as ACC_NbTickets,
account.TECH_NbDeTicketsOuverts__c            as ACC_NbTicketsOuverts,
account.TECH_DateDuDernierTicketCree__c       as ACC_DateDernierTicketOuvert,
account.PersonContactId                       as ACC_SubscriberKey,
OPPPROD.UnitPrice                             as OPPPROD_UnitPrice,
OPPPROD.Quantity                              as OPPPROD_Quantity,
OPPPROD.Prix_Total_TTC__c                     as OPPPROD_PrixTotalTTC,
OPPPROD.Id                                    as OPPPROD_Id,
biggest_price                                 as max_price,
PROD.Name                                     as PROD_Name,
PROD.Marche__c                                as PROD_Marche,
PROD.Type_de_produit__c                       as PROD_TypeProduit,
PROD.Marque_groupe__c                         as PROD_MarqueGroupe,
PROD.Categorie_Ecommerce__c                   as PROD_CategorieCFP,
PROD.Sous_categorie_Ecommerce__c              as PROD_SousCategorieCFP,
PROD.ProductCode                              as PROD_ProductCode

FROM 
(
 SELECT
opportunity.Id,
opportunity.Amount,
opportunity.CreatedDate,
MAX(OPPPROD.UnitPrice) as biggest_price 

FROM Opportunity_Salesforce opportunity

RIGHT JOIN OpportunityLineItem_Salesforce OPPPROD
ON OPPPROD.OpportunityId = opportunity.Id

Group By opportunity.Id,opportunity.Amount,opportunity.CreatedDate
) as opportunity


RIGHT JOIN OpportunityLineItem_Salesforce OPPPROD
ON opportunity.Id = OPPPROD.OpportunityId

LEFT JOIN Product2_Salesforce PROD
ON OPPPROD.Product2Id = PROD.Id

INNER JOIN Account_Salesforce account
ON opportunity.AccountId = account.Id
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Data Extension, but looking at your query as such: You're referring to the AccountId on the opportunity, but your opportunity definition does not include AccountId in its SELECT. May be add it there (like you do for opportunity.Id)?!

Comment: Yeah, you're missing an alias on `opportunity.Id,` in your inner query.  Should be `opportunity.Id as AccountId,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the windowing function [row_number()](https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-the-sql-row-number-function/) and a partition for returning the Opportunity with the highest `unitPrice`:

```sql
Select top 1 with ties
  o.Id                                  as OPP_Id
, o.Name                                as OPP_Name
, o.StageName                           as OPP_Stage
, o.Loss_Reason__c                      as OPP_RaisonDeLaPerte
, o.LeadSource                          as OPP_LeadSource
, o.Pr_cision_source__c                 as OPP_PrecisionSource
, o.Amount                              as OPP_Amount
, o.IsWon                               as OPP_IsWon
, o.MYOPLA__c                           as OPP_Myopla
, o.MarqueGroupe__c                     as OPP_MarqueGroupe
, o.CreatedDate                         as OPP_CreatedDate
, o.CloseDate                           as OPP_CloseDate
, o.LastModifiedDate                    as OPP_LastModifiedDate
, o.Cat_gorie_Produits__c               as OPP_CategorieProduit
, a.FirstName                           as ACC_FirstName
, a.LastName                            as ACC_LastName
, a.IsPersonAccount                     as ACC_IsPersonAccount
, a.ShippingCity                        as ACC_ShippingCity
, a.ShippingCountry                     as ACC_ShippingCountry
, a.ShippingStreet                      as ACC_ShippingStreet
, a.ShippingPostalCode                  as ACC_ShippingPostalCode
, a.PersonEmail                         as ACC_Email
, a.PersonMobilePhone                   as ACC_Mobile
, a.et4ae5__Mobile_Country_Code__pc     as ACC_MobileCountryCode
, a.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail            as ACC_DesabonnementEmail
, a.et4ae5__HasOptedOutOfMobile__pc     as ACC_DesabonnementMobile
, a.CreatedDate                         as ACC_CreatedDate
, a.Account_Source__pc                  as ACC_AccountSource
, a.Precision_source__c                 as ACC_PrecisionSource
, a.Marque_groupe__c                    as ACC_MarqueGroupe
, a.NbDeCommandesPassees__c             as ACC_NbCommandesPassees
, a.TECH_PanierMoyen__c                 as ACC_PanierMoyen
, a.TECH_DateDerniereCommande__c        as ACC_DateDerniereCommande
, a.TECH_MontantDeLaDerniereCommande__c as ACC_MontantDerniereCommande
, a.TECH_NbCases__pc                    as ACC_NbTickets
, a.TECH_NbDeTicketsOuverts__c          as ACC_NbTicketsOuverts
, a.TECH_DateDuDernierTicketCree__c     as ACC_DateDernierTicketOuvert
, a.PersonContactId                     as ACC_SubscriberKey
, oi.UnitPrice                          as oi_UnitPrice
, oi.Quantity                           as oi_Quantity
, oi.Prix_Total_TTC__c                  as oi_PrixTotalTTC
, oi.Id                                 as oi_Id
, oi.UnitPrice                          as max_price
, p.Name                                as PROD_Name
, p.Marche__c                           as PROD_Marche
, p.Type_de_produit__c                  as PROD_TypeProduit
, p.Marque_groupe__c                    as PROD_MarqueGroupe
, p.Categorie_Ecommerce__c              as PROD_CategorieCFP
, p.Sous_categorie_Ecommerce__c         as PROD_SousCategorieCFP
, p.ProductCode                         as PROD_ProductCode
FROM Opportunity_Salesforce o
INNER JOIN Account_Salesforce a ON a.Id = o.AccountId
INNER JOIN OpportunityLineItem_Salesforce oi ON oi.OpportunityId = o.Id
INNER JOIN Product2_Salesforce p ON p.Id = oi.Product2Id 
order by row_number() over (partition by o.id order by oi.UnitPrice desc)
```

This query joins the tables together and orders the duplicates by `oi.UnitPrice` and returns only the top one per `o.id`.

Seems like you'd only want to return Opportunities with line items and products.  Changing your joins to Inner, instead of Left and Right would accomplish that.

Comment: Thank you so much @AdamSpriggs ! It is working :)